# when going back to cmake project from C# solution in visual studio 2019 Resharper intellisense stops working

Tags: c#, c++, cmake, resharper, intellisense

I have resharper intellisense for C# and C++, a C# solution is nested in a cmake project, when I open the cmake project the C++ intellisense works, then when I open the C# solution the C# intellisense works too but when I go back to the cmake project the C++ intellisense does not work any more. For switching between projects I'm using the Switch between solutions and available views button.

how to avoid this behavior?

one more thing the folder name on the VS top bar changes when entering the VS solution but not when going back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, I've filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-32523 to track it.